# swf every time reloading in iframe in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, flash, iframe

I am using AngularJs 1.6.3 version for my project. Here i faced one problem while displaying flash swf in iframe.

Here i have one html file and its controller. Here that html file has one iframe to load flash swf file.

I have one button, whenever i click that button it will create one angular js state with that html and its controller. Each state included by ng-include in one single div.

When i am switching to one state to another state every time that flash swf reloaded it happening in FireFox browser only, in chrome its working fine.

Other websites link also i put in iframe that also not reloading everytime.

I have spent full day for this but it could not find solution.

You guys have any idea or solution please share here it will help a lot to me.

Thanks,
Selvam

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code.

Comment: Or show demo page of such issue so others can advise properly.

Answer (score 0):

> - *"Html file has one iframe to load flash swf file...  Every time that Flash SWF reloaded"*
> - *"Other websites link also i put in iframe that also not reloading everytime."*

Try embedding the SWF inside HTML file (see [**example code**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_embed))...
Then simply load the same (container) HTML file inside your `<iframe>`.